# A strange trigonometric identity in a proof of Niven's theorem

Tags: trigonometry

I can't understand the inductive step on Lemma A in [this proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Niven%27s_Theorem) of Niven's theorem. It asserts, where $n$ is an integer:

$$2\cos ((n-1)t)\cos (t) = \cos (nt) + \cos ((n-2)t)$$

I tried applying the angle subtraction formula to both sides, but all that does is introduce a bunch of sines, which I can't see how to eliminate.

Comment: The answer by @lab is good. You can also do it by replacing each cosine with exponentials via $\cos x=(1/2)(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As

$\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B)=\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B+\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B=2\cos A\cos B$

Put $A+B=nt,A-B=(n-2)t$

Alternatively use $\cos C+\cos D=2\cos\frac{C+D}2\cos\frac{C-D}2$

Comment: This is also called Prosthaphaeresis Formulas(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)